# Android internet app doesn't render mobile website version properly

Tags: javascript, android, aurelia

So the case is - when I run my website under Android Chrome, it's all ok, but when I open it up in the default "internet" app, it doesn't render some html markup and js is run only to some extent. I used the Aurelia.js framework for coding it. How can I debug this behavior? Is there a way to somehow see the errors in js console on Androids default internet app?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on a version of android you're testing on

as google says

`Since Android 4.4 (KitKat), the WebView component is based on the Chromium open source project. WebViews now include an updated version of the V8 JavaScript engine and support for modern web standards previously missing in old WebViews. New Web views also share the same rendering engine as Chrome for Android, so rendering should be much more consistent between the WebView and Chrome.`
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview

So if you testing on android version before 4.4 you may not test it on chromium based browser

Comment: Don't think injecting chromium is relevant here. It's a website, not a downloaded app (APK).

Comment: @Benny Yes you'r right, I should mention before that if you want to have application with webview you can inject chromium, answer edited